# Use GIT-Extensions tool to compare 2 branches?

Tags: git-extensions

I am fully aware of how to compare two branches via `git diff` through command line but; I am specifically curious if there is a way through the GITExt GUI?

I enjoy the tool a lot and cannot seem to find a way that the tool, at the moment of posting, has this capability?

That, OR I have missed it. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the revision grid you can select the first commit, then with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> select another commit. In the "Diff" tab you will see the diff between the commits.

[image]

Alternatively, you can use "Compare" options via the context menu:
[image]

Comment: Is there any comparable tool that runs on Linux? They discontinued development for Linux.

Comment: v2.5x are still runnable on Linux with Mono.
I heard anecdotes of people running v3 and v4 on Linux with Wine, but I haven't seen that myself.

Comment: I went with Meld as it is native for Linux. It is also not limited to Git repos but can compare directories as well, which comes in handy at times ....